# SQLAlchemy - column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy with postgresql,

Tables

```
Shape[id, name, timestamp, user_id]#user_id referring id column in user table
User[id, name]
```

this query -

```
        query1 = self.session.query(Shape.timestamp, Shape.name, User.id,
            extract('day', Shape.timestamp).label('day'),
            extract('hour', Shape.timestamp).label('hour'),
            func.count(Shape.id).label("total"),
            )\
        .join(User, User.id==Shape.user_id)\
        .filter(Shape.timestamp.between(from_datetime, to_datetime))\
        .group_by(Shape.user_id)\
        .group_by('hour')\
        .all()
```

this works well in sqlite3+sqlalchemy, but it is not working in postgresql+sqlalchemy

I got this error -> `(psycopg2.errors.GroupingError) column "Shape.timestamp" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

I need to group only by the `user_id` and the `hour` in the timestamp, where the `Shape.timestamp` is the `DateTime` python object

but, the error saying to add the `Shape.timestamp` in the `group_by` function also,
If i add the `Shape.timestamp` in the `group_by`, then it shows all the records

If i need to use some function on other columns, then how i will get the other column actual data, is there any way to get the column data as it is without adding in `group_by` or using some function

How to solve this

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic SQL issue, what if in your group, there is several `timestamp` values ?

You either need to use an aggregator function (`COUNT`, `MIN`, `MAX`, `AVG`) or specify it in your `GROUP BY`.

**NB.** SQLite allows ungrouped columns in `GROUP BY`, in which case "*it is evaluated against a single arbitrarily chosen row from within the group.*" ([SQLite doc](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) section 2.4)

Comment: is there any function, which simply returns the data - like passing function

Comment: what do you mean passing? If you have in group `X` the following timestamps `2022-01-01T00:00:01`, `2022-01-01T00:00:02`, `2022-01-01T00:00:05`, which one should it return ? `MIN`, `MAX`, `AVG` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the 9 line ->

```
query1 = self.session.query(Shape.timestamp, Shape.name, User.id,
            extract('day', Shape.timestamp).label('day'),
            extract('hour', Shape.timestamp).label('hour'),
            func.count(Shape.id).label("total"),
            )\
        .join(User, User.id==Shape.user_id)\
        .filter(Shape.timestamp.between(from_datetime, to_datetime))\
        .group_by(Shape.user_id)\
        .group_by(extract('hour', Shape.timestamp))\
        .all()
```

Comment: I tried, same error happening